# Using grep to find lines that each contain ALL search strings

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have a file which contains a lot of lines similar to this:

```
{"id": 2796, "some_model": "Profile", "message_type": "MODEL_SAVE", "fields": {"account": 14, "address": null, "modification_timestamp": "2014-03-19T10:46:33.543Z", "was_deleted": false}}
```

But then I want to find all the lines which will contain some pieces of the respective lines I want only. An example that will be applied in the example line above would be:

```
~$ grep '2796' file.log | grep 'Profile' | grep 'another_more' | grep 'so_on'
```

I tried doing the same way as above, **EDITED**: It did work, but was not quite enough to bring all the necessary data. I mean, there were missing data in the results of the search. :(

Following the idea of `grep 'word' filename` it works, but just one word in a mountain of data is not enough. So, how to pass multiple 'word' to match what I really want? What I really want is a search by the '*ID*', '*some_model*' and '*account*' using grep at the same time.

How do I do that search to match all the possible lines with those arguments in the prompt?
This is more like a doubt, is possible to use conditions like `if` and `else` o `while` too combining with grep for example?

If the questions are not clear, please let me know to right it.
Thanks to all.

Comment: Yes, your question isn't quite clear.  Examples might help.

Comment: @devnull, yeah alright. It's edited! Thanks! :D

Comment: Do you want lines matching all the words or any of the words?

Comment: @devnull, all the words.

Comment: @devnull, well I'll try that out. Thanks for now!

Comment: "I tried doing the same way as above, but it wont work! :(" - could you elaborate on what you tried, and what exactly didn't work?  Ideally, you should provide an example input, and the expected output, then we can suggest how to formulate `grep` or another tool to get that output.  Presently it's entirely unclear what you're trying to get back.

Comment: It sounds like you want the following: You want to find lines that EACH contain ALL search strings specified in ANY ORDER. Can you please confirm? Your `grep ... | grep ...` approach SHOULD work, incidentally, but it's inefficient - perhaps that's why you're asking: to find a more efficient solution.

Comment: For a JSON-aware tool, you'd do much better to use jq.

Comment: @mklement0, Yes, you are right. I want to find lines that EACH contain ALL search strings specified in ANY ORDER. Yeah, the example I showed it did work, but was not efficient I think because there were missing data in the results of the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This question specifically asks about `grep`, but really `sed` or `awk` are much cleaner for 'a AND b'-style matches, see [How to run grep with multiple AND patterns?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55391/19157)*

*This answer covers how to use `grep` to match all lines which match all inputs - [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22883906/using-grep-to-find-lines-that-each-contain-all-search-strings/22884144#22884144) covers matching any input.*

Note that `grep` is more powerful than simple word-matching, it can match arbitrary patterns, including multiple words.

Consider the following simplified version of the example you provide:

```
$ cat file
{"id": 2796, "some_model": "Profile", "was_deleted": false}
{"id": 2797, "some_model": "Profile", "was_deleted": true}
{"id": 2798, "some_model": "Another", "was_deleted": false}
```

You could find item 2796 like so:

```
$ grep '"\?id"\? *: *2796 *,\?' file
{"id": 2796, "some_model": "Profile", "was_deleted": false}
```

Or find all non-deleted items:

```
$ grep '"\?was_deleted"\? *: *false *[,}]' file
{"id": 2796, "some_model": "Profile", "was_deleted": false}
{"id": 2798, "some_model": "Another", "was_deleted": false}
```

You can even combine the two, to only get item 2796 if it's not deleted (change `false` to `true` and the line no longer matches):

```
$ grep '"\?id"\? *: *2796 *,\?.*"\?was_deleted"\? *: *false *[,}]' file
{"id": 2796, "some_model": "Profile", "was_deleted": false}
```

Or roughly equivalent, using the grep-piping syntax you use above:

```
$ grep '"\?id"\? *: *2796 *,\?' file | grep '"\?was_deleted"\? *: *false *[,}]'
{"id": 2796, "some_model": "Profile", "was_deleted": false}
```

These examples hopefully look tricky to get right, because this is not a good idea!

The data you're working with looks to be JSON, a structured data format which grep is not well suited for processing.  Valid JSON could be split across multiple lines or have fields in arbitrary order, which will break the above patterns.  Not to mention arbitrary white-space (`*`), semi-optional quotes (`"\?`), and end of field vs. end of object markers (`[,}]`) which the above patterns should handle, but are easy to get wrong.

**If you are trying to query JSON data, you need a JSON parser**, which grep is not.  http://www.json.org/ offers links to several popular JSON parsers in many languages, see if any of those will suite your needs.  You will have much better success with a real tool than trying to construct complicated regular expressions.

Comment: If you're trying to query JSON data, I recommend jq: http://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Answer (score 3):

You could use `sed`:

```
sed '/string1/!d; /string2/!d; /string3/!d; /string4/!d' filename
```

This would produce only the lines containing all the strings in any order.

Same thing using `awk`:

```
awk '/string1/ && /string2/ && /string3/ && /string4/' filename
```

Comment: +1; ingenious use of `sed`; matches lines containing _all_ strings in _any_ order.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer covers how to use grep to match all lines which match one of many inputs - [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22883906/using-grep-to-find-lines-that-each-contain-all-search-strings/22884549#22884549) covers matching all input, which the OP was actually looking for.  I suspect this answer is more commonly what people are looking for, so I'm leaving it here.*

The `-e` parameter lets you search for multiple different matches:

```
$ cat file
Hello World
Nope
Foo Bar

$ grep -e Hello -e Foo file
Hello World
Foo Bar
```

You can also use the `|` character to delimit multiple matches in a single query, but you have to escape it with a `\` and quote the query string, like so:

```
$ grep 'Hello\|Foo' file
Hello World
Foo Bar
```

Or use the `f` flag to have grep use patterns specified in a file:

```
$ cat patterns
Hello
Foo

$ grep -f patterns file
Hello World
Foo Bar
```

Needless to say, I personally prefer using `-e`, but there are many options.

Comment: Does it match any line with "first OR second word" or match only "first AND second word at same line" ?

Comment: My examples returns lines matching any of the provided patterns.  The `grep A | grep B | grep C` pattern posted in the question will let you find lines that have `A`, `B`, and `C` all in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` version. This is restrictive in the find order, so `string1` comes before `string2`

```
awk '/string1.*string2.*string3.*string4/' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is answered in the official GNU grep documentation:

http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/grep/manual/grep.html#Usage

```
10.  I can do “OR” with ‘|’, but what about “AND”?

    grep 'paul' /etc/motd | grep 'franc,ois' 

finds all lines that contain both ‘paul’ and ‘franc,ois’.
```

Looks like the only way to achieve a logical *AND* using `grep`, that is not dependent of the order in where the matching patterns are found.